# Display standard page within salesforce using Iframe

Tags: visualforce, iframe

I have a question using Iframes to display standard pages in visualforce. Since salesforce users different domain for custom page and standard page, browser blocks the iframe content ('X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN').

Is there a way to resolve this?  is there alternative way to handle this?

Comment: Can you add some more information about your requirement?

Comment: I have a custom visualforce page which has multiple panels, in the main panel displays the details using standard page which has standard approval process. When user try to approve the page is blank.